# The benefits of std::string not storing the data in a contiguous memory location (pre C++11)

Tags: c++, string, memory

In `C++98` and `C++03` `std::string` could have stored it's underling data in a non-contiguous memory. What was the reason for this? What possible optimization could have been achieved by this relaxed requirement? Did any compiler/architecture actually make use of this?

If you have parts of the string stored in different memory locations, wouldn't the iterator be overly complicated? And the class too, as it would need to know exactly where different parts of the string are.

Comment: There is no reason why the iterator would be overly complicated. It could be implemented as `pair<string *, size_t>`, with `operator *` indexing the string, `operator ++` incrementing the index, and so on. The class would of course have to know where the different parts are, but that can be very efficient if stored in a balanced tree. See [rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)).

Comment: Here's another pro/con for the rope implementation (which - as I understand - the standard had in mind as something that should be possible): http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The chief reason was that string concatenation could take place without re-allocation. I believe that early versions of STLPort exploited this.

Another reason is that it was possible to implement copy-on-write or even partial copy-on-write. Although other requirements demanded of `std::string` (especially the move semantics of C++11) now mean this is no longer possible.

Comment: wouldn't the iterator would be overly complicated? Also the class would be complicated as you would need to know exactly where the parts of your string are.

Comment: Without giving it too much thought, I'd have thought that iteration was little more complicated than a simple traversal for contiguous parts coupled with a linked-list type idiom.

Comment: @bolov: re iterators: bearably so. Iterator would contain a reference to the segment, and an offset into the segment. If segments were held in a doubly linked list or anything bidirectionally iterable, it's *"one additional `if`"*.

Comment: @peterchen, ok, in the iterator you have 1 more `if`. But in order to support that you need a linked list... Anyway I see your point.

Comment: @bolov: the iterator is not overly complicated for `std::deque` that also doesn't use contiguous memory